# Grab Gridview textbox input value Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have built the following Gridview (Employees and their weekly target):

[image: Gridview of consultants and their targets]

**Desired result:** I have a submit button at the bottom which will take all the data from the Gridview using jQuery and push it into my database.

At the moment, I cannot even retrieve the textbox values though, i have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                $("#GridView1 td").each(function () {

                var value = $(this).text();
                alert(value);
                });
        });
});
```

This Selects all the "Table Data" cells... It is selecting the names perfectly, but as soon as it gets to a textbox, it doesnt get the value I type in, it just alerts nothing.

I have tried the following too, each with different, but not the desired results:

```
.html
.val
.innerHTML
```

Would anyone be able to point out where I am going wrong please? please let me know if you need anymore info...

Comment: You have to check for the controls in the table cells!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the control exists in the table cells or not 
Give this a try

```
var value = $(this).find('input').length > 0 ? $(this).find('input').val() : $(this).text();
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: @Mike Glad to hear it! Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You must select the input textbox in your selection as given below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        $("#GridView1 td input").each(function () {

            var value = $(this).val();
            alert(value);
        });
    });
});
```